# Django editable list view

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

What's the correct way to make the elements in a ListView editable? I believe I should be using an inline_formsetfactory however I am not sure how to display the objects including data that I don't want to be editable.

For example - the editable fields that are in the form are just 'status' and 'visible'. However I'd like to display the title, id and other data associated with the objects in the list view - just not have them editable.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a form class that includes/excludes the fields you need, and hand that to your formset factory.

Comment: The issue is I want to display some fields of each object that are not editable (ie. they shouldn't be in the form).

Comment: I see. You can write your template such that not all fields are shown as form elements. Just loop over the forms in the formset in your template and you'll have full control over the HTML.